# Subtle meaning difference in usage of adverb vs adjective in here

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> 1. our current vague knowledge

> 2. our currently vague knowledge

As far as I know the two above phrases are grammatically correct. In the first one both adjectives "current" and "vague" modify the noun "knowledge" and in the second one the adverb "currently" modifies "vague" and the adjective "vague" modifies "knowledge".

How do they differ in conveying meaning?

I think the first one tells us our current knowledge which is vague. But the second one implicitly implies that our knowledge is currently vague, but it is not permanent and in the future it may become more clear. Did I grasp their subtle difference correctly?

Comment: No - I'd say you're not correctly guessing a difference, because for most purposes *they mean the same thing*. But note that idiomatically we [nearly always](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=our+current+vague%2Cour+currently+vague&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cour%20current%20vague%3B%2Cc0) use the "flat adjective" ***current*** in the cited context, so if someone happens to use the explicitly adverbial form ***currently***, we naturally assume there's a *reason*. And the natural reason to assign is "emphasis" (that things *will* improve).

Comment: Note that to a considerable extent, our current and projected future "knowledge" are actually *the same thing*. If that knowledge is modified by both ***current / currently*** AND another adjective like ***vague***, the explicitly adverbial ***-ly*** form (which we tend to avoid, because it sounds a bit clumsy here), creates a stronger semantic link between "currency" and "vagueness". With a consequent stronger implication that if we do away with "currently" (by moving into the future) we can also do away with "vague" (which attaches more strongly to "currently" than to "knowledge").

Comment: In 1. ("our current vague knowledge"), "knowledge" is first modified by "vague" to form the nominal "vague knowledge", and this in turn is modified by "current" giving the meaning "knowledge that is current by the normal standards of"vague knowledge". In 2. the adverb "currently" modifies "vague" giving the meaning "knowledge that is currently vague".